# How "customizable" is Picasso vs. Universal Image Loader (UIL)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

My goal is to use one large image containing a textured background for my Android app.  At run-time I want cut out a screen-size piece of it and place it as the background image.

Which Image Loader would be better for this?

[This review](http://java.dzone.com/articles/be-lazy-productive-android-0) of Android Image Loader libraries described some procs and cons of the Picasso library and the UIL library (among others).

So far I think Picasso seems to match my needs.  "Picasso allows you to specify 
exact target image size."  I believe this would accomplish my goal of cropping out a specific size of image, based on the device's screen size and density.

This article claims that UIL allows for a lot of customization, but then it also says it "doesn’t not provide a way to specify image size directly you want to load into a view".

Am I correct that Picasso will better allow me to crop an image to the size of the actual screen size?

Comment: Take a look at Fresco from facebook

Comment: Don't forget to look at Glide, which is essentially Picasso on steroids: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if I remember correctly, Picasso isn't able to crop an image out of the box. But, Picasso allows you to code transformations, and specify their use, as part of the loading process.

```
Picasso.with(ctx).load(uri)
    .transform(new YourCropTransform(params...))
    .into(target)
```

Comment: I'm planning to include the image as part of the drawable folder (so it will come with the app (or with the APK).  So Picasso wouldn't let me manipulate an image resource?  How about UIL?

Comment: Picasso allows for loading from a resource. Just stick in the R.drawable.your_image into load